# Test succeeds in Idea IntelliJ but fails using Maven command

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

I have a very simple unit test, as simple as it could be

```
  @Test
  public void testHandleInterruptedException() {
  InterruptedException exception = Mockito.mock(InterruptedException.class);
  Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.TRUE));
  Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.FALSE));
  }
```

Strangely, this tests fails while running from maven build command and passes while running in IntelliJ.

The method handleInterruptedException simple too -

```
  public static KendraConnectorException handleInterruptedException(
  InterruptedException e, boolean isContinuable) {

  return isContinuable ? new ContinuableInternalServerError(
    "Current thread has been interrupted", e)
    : new InternalServerError("Please try again later", e);
}
```

I am not sure why it fails with maven command.

Edit 1-
Complete YammerServiceTest class -  May be I am doing something incorrect in test class

```
        package com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.yammer.client;

        import com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.sdk.exception.BadRequestException;
        import com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.sdk.exception.ContinuableInternalServerError;
        import com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.yammer.configuration.YammerConfiguration;
        import com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.yammer.rest.client.api.MyselfApi;
        import com.amazonaws.kendra.connector.yammer.service.UserService;
        import feign.FeignException;
        import java.net.UnknownHostException;
        import java.util.Arrays;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Objects;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
        import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
        import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
        import org.mockito.Mockito;
        import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
        import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoSettings;
        import org.mockito.quality.Strictness;

        @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
        @MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
        public class YammerServiceTest {
          private MockedStatic<UserService> userService =
              Mockito.mockStatic(UserService.class);
          private YammerConfiguration yammerConfiguration =
              Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
          private MyselfApi myselfApi = Mockito.mock(MyselfApi.class);

          @BeforeEach
          public void setUp() {
            userService.when(() -> UserService.getMyselfApi(Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(myselfApi);
            Mockito.when(myselfApi.getCurrentUser()).thenReturn(DataProvider.getUser());
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getHostUrl()).thenReturn(DataProvider.URL);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getAuthType()).thenReturn(DataProvider.OAUTH2);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getClientId()).thenReturn(DataProvider.CLIENT_ID);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getClientSecret()).thenReturn(DataProvider.CLIENT_SECRET);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getUserName()).thenReturn(DataProvider.USER_NAME);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getPassword()).thenReturn(DataProvider.PASSWORD);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getScope()).thenReturn(DataProvider.SCOPE);
          }

          @AfterEach
          void tearDown() {
            if (!Objects.isNull(userService)) {
              userService.close();
            }
            userService = null;
          }

          @Test
          public void testReTestConnection() {
            YammerConfiguration yammerConfiguration = Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
            YammerService yammerService = new YammerService();
            Assertions.assertTrue(yammerService.reTestConnection(yammerConfiguration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testTestConnection() {
            YammerService yammerService = new YammerService();
            Assertions.assertTrue(yammerService.testConnection(yammerConfiguration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testReTestConnectionWhenFeignExceptionIsThrown() {
            YammerConfiguration configuration = Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
            FeignException exception = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getHostUrl()).thenThrow(exception);
            Mockito.when(exception.status()).thenReturn(429);
            Assertions.assertFalse(YammerService.reTestConnection(configuration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testReTestConnectionWhenFeignExceptionIsThrown_1() {
            YammerConfiguration configuration = Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
            FeignException exception = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getHostUrl()).thenThrow(exception);
            Mockito.when(exception.status()).thenReturn(430);
            Assertions.assertFalse(YammerService.reTestConnection(configuration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testTestConnectionWhenFeignExceptionIsThrown() {
            YammerConfiguration configuration = Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
            FeignException exception = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getHostUrl()).thenReturn(DataProvider.URL);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getAuthType()).thenThrow(exception);
            Mockito.when(exception.status()).thenReturn(430);
            Mockito.when(exception.getCause()).thenReturn(exception);
            Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class,
                () -> YammerService.testConnection(configuration));
          }

          //@Test
          public void testTestConnectionWithThrotlingWhenFeignExceptionIsThrown() {
            YammerConfiguration configuration = Mockito.mock(YammerConfiguration.class);
            FeignException exception = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getHostUrl()).thenReturn(DataProvider.URL);
            Mockito.when(configuration.getAuthType()).thenThrow(exception);
            Mockito.when(exception.status()).thenReturn(429);
            Mockito.when(exception.getCause()).thenReturn(exception);
            Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class,
                () -> YammerService.testConnection(configuration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testHandleInterruptedException() {
            InterruptedException exception = new InterruptedException("InterruptedException");
            Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.TRUE));
            Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.FALSE));
          }

          @Test
          public void testTestConnectionWhenNotAuth2() {
            YammerService yammerService = new YammerService();
            List<Integer> waitTimeList =
                Arrays.asList(1);
            FeignException feignException = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(feignException.status()).thenReturn(429);
            Mockito.when(feignException.getCause()).thenReturn(new UnknownHostException());
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getAuthType()).thenReturn(DataProvider.OAUTH);
            userService.when(() -> UserService.getMyselfApi(Mockito.any()))
                .thenThrow(feignException);
            Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () ->
                yammerService.testConnection(yammerConfiguration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testTestConnectionFeignExceptionIsThrown() {
            YammerService yammerService = new YammerService();
            List<Integer> waitTimeList =
                Arrays.asList(1);
            FeignException feignException = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(feignException.status()).thenReturn(429);
            Mockito.when(feignException.getCause()).thenReturn(new Exception());
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getAuthType()).thenReturn(DataProvider.OAUTH);
            userService.when(() -> UserService.getMyselfApi(Mockito.any()))
                .thenThrow(feignException);
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            Assertions.assertThrows(ContinuableInternalServerError.class, () ->
                yammerService.testConnection(yammerConfiguration));
          }

          @Test
          public void testTestConnectionWhenCauseIsNull() {
            YammerService yammerService = new YammerService();
            List<Integer> waitTimeList =
                Arrays.asList(1);
            FeignException feignException = Mockito.mock(FeignException.class);
            Mockito.when(feignException.status()).thenReturn(429);
            Mockito.when(feignException.getCause()).thenReturn(null);
            Mockito.when(yammerConfiguration.getAuthType()).thenReturn(DataProvider.OAUTH);
            userService.when(() -> UserService.getMyselfApi(Mockito.any()))
                .thenThrow(feignException);
            Assertions.assertThrows(BadRequestException.class, () ->
                yammerService.testConnection(yammerConfiguration));
          }


        }
```

Comment: How does the test fail, exactly?

Comment: YammerServiceTest.testHandleInterruptedException:127 expected: not <null>
It is still failing here from maven command

Comment: What maven command line are you using, exactly?

Comment: mvn clean install -s settings.xml     -- The setting.xml contains credentials for code artifacts.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your entire `YammerServiceTest` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an object and send it to the service rather than mock it

```
@Test
public void testHandleInterruptedException() {
  // Arrange
  InterruptedException exception = new InterruptedException("Test Interrupted exception msg");

  // Act & Assert
  Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.TRUE));
  Assertions.assertNotNull(YammerService.handleInterruptedException(exception, Boolean.FALSE));
}
```

Comment: YammerServiceTest.testHandleInterruptedException:127 expected: not <null> Still failing

Comment: Do you use any variables or something that you should remove after the test is executed?

Comment: I just added complete test class , please check the question

Comment: The `before` and `after` if you set something and forget to reset it?

Comment: private MockedStatic<UserService> userService =            Mockito.mockStatic(UserService.class); this mocking was not done properly in test classes. Need to be very careful , we have to close such static mock ,should not do in test method, it should be at class level